# How to achieve a token price of 0.0000001 ether?

Tags: contract-development

How can i achieve (working with mist) a token price below 1 ether?
I know i have to use wei within the contract.
My problem is, while working with mist, that i only can use uint as token price within the form.

I tried deploying the contract with the amount of wei instead of 0.0000001 ether - but that resulted a lot of ether to pay for one token.

[image: screenshot mist]
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

```
contract token { function transfer(address receiver, uint amount) public ;
                 function mintToken(address target, uint mintedAmount) public ;
                }

contract CrowdSale {
    enum State {
        Fundraising,
        Failed,
        Successful,
        Closed
    }
    State public state = State.Fundraising;

    struct Contribution {
        uint amount;
        address contributor;
    }
    Contribution[] contributions;



    uint public totalRaised;
    uint public currentBalance;
    uint public deadline;
    uint public completedAt;
    uint public priceInWei;
    uint public fundingMinimumTargetInWei; 
    uint public fundingMaximumTargetInWei; 
    token public tokenReward;
    address public creator;
    address public beneficiary; 
    string campaignUrl;
    byte constant version = "1";


    event LogFundingReceived(address addr, uint amount, uint currentTotal);
    event LogWinnerPaid(address winnerAddress);
    event LogFundingSuccessful(uint totalRaised);
    event LogFunderInitialized(
        address creator,
        address beneficiary,
        string url,
        uint _fundingMaximumTargetInEther, 
        uint256 deadline);


    modifier inState(State _state) {
        require(state == _state) ;
        _;
    }

     modifier isMinimum() {
        require(msg.value > priceInWei) ;
        _;
    }

    modifier inMultipleOfPrice() {
        require(msg.value%priceInWei == 0) ;
        _;
    }

    modifier isCreator() {
        require(msg.sender == creator) ;
        _;
    }


    modifier atEndOfLifecycle() {
        if(!((state == State.Failed || state == State.Successful) && completedAt + 1 hours < now)) {
            revert();
        }
        _;
    }


    function CrowdSale(
        uint _timeInMinutesForFundraising,
        string _campaignUrl,
        address _ifSuccessfulSendTo,
        uint _fundingMinimumTargetInEther,
        uint _fundingMaximumTargetInEther,
        token _addressOfTokenUsedAsReward,
        uint _etherCostOfEachToken) public
    {
        creator = msg.sender;
        beneficiary = _ifSuccessfulSendTo;
        campaignUrl = _campaignUrl;
        fundingMinimumTargetInWei = _fundingMinimumTargetInEther * 1 ether; 
        fundingMaximumTargetInWei = _fundingMaximumTargetInEther * 1 ether; 
        deadline = now + (_timeInMinutesForFundraising * 1 minutes);
        currentBalance = 0;
        tokenReward = token(_addressOfTokenUsedAsReward);
        priceInWei = _etherCostOfEachToken * 100000000000 wei;
        LogFunderInitialized(
            creator,
            beneficiary,
            campaignUrl,
            fundingMaximumTargetInWei,
            deadline);
    }

    function contribute()
    public
    inState(State.Fundraising) isMinimum() inMultipleOfPrice() payable returns (uint256)
    {
        uint256 amountInWei = msg.value;


        contributions.push(
            Contribution({
                amount: msg.value,
                contributor: msg.sender
                }) 
            );

        totalRaised += msg.value;
        currentBalance = totalRaised;


        if(fundingMaximumTargetInWei != 0){

            tokenReward.transfer(msg.sender, amountInWei / priceInWei);
        }
        else{
            tokenReward.mintToken(msg.sender, amountInWei / priceInWei);
        }

        LogFundingReceived(msg.sender, msg.value, totalRaised);



        checkIfFundingCompleteOrExpired();
        return contributions.length - 1; 
    }

    function checkIfFundingCompleteOrExpired() public {


        if (fundingMaximumTargetInWei != 0 && totalRaised > fundingMaximumTargetInWei) {
            state = State.Successful;
            LogFundingSuccessful(totalRaised);
            payOut();
            completedAt = now;

            } else if ( now > deadline )  {
                if(totalRaised >= fundingMinimumTargetInWei){
                    state = State.Successful;
                    LogFundingSuccessful(totalRaised);
                    payOut();  
                    completedAt = now;
                }
                else{
                    state = State.Failed; 
                    completedAt = now;
                }
            } 

    }

        function payOut()
        public
        inState(State.Successful)
        {

            if(!beneficiary.send(this.balance)) {
                revert();
            }

            state = State.Closed;
            currentBalance = 0;
            LogWinnerPaid(beneficiary);
        }

        function getRefund()
        public
        inState(State.Failed) 
        returns (bool)
        {
            for(uint i=0; i<=contributions.length; i++)
            {
                if(contributions[i].contributor == msg.sender){
                    uint amountToRefund = contributions[i].amount;
                    contributions[i].amount = 0;
                    if(!contributions[i].contributor.send(amountToRefund)) {
                        contributions[i].amount = amountToRefund;
                        return false;
                    }
                    else{
                        totalRaised -= amountToRefund;
                        currentBalance = totalRaised;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        function removeContract()
        public
        isCreator()
        atEndOfLifecycle()
        {
            selfdestruct(msg.sender);

        }

        function () public { revert(); }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code looks quite strange. It accepts a parameter called `_etherCostOfEachToken`, but it multiplies it by only 100000000000 wei (0.0000001 ether).

So as written, you can get the value 0.0000001 ether into `priceInWei` by passing in the value `1`, but there's something quite strange going on.

Without seeing the rest of the code, I don't know whether `priceInWei` is, in fact, being treated as the price per token in wei.

Comment: Hey smarx, i added the full code. Thanks for your support!

Comment: It doesn't look like the token's `decimals` value is taken into account anywhere, so though the price is indeed counted in wei, the amount of the token transferred is probably incredibly low. (Assuming the default 18 decimals, paying the `priceInWei` will get you only 1/10**18 of a token.)

Comment: Hmm that sounds to be far away from the goal i try to achieve.
My goal is to have a smart contract crowdsale, where someone can buy 1 million token for 0.1 ETH.

Comment: Do you recommend someone who could help with this thingy? I am not a fulltime dev - so i guess i need to buy in some help to get more into it :-)